# Displaying a blank ng-repeat on purpose (for a nested array)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm iterating (ng-repeat) over a childArray of an existing loop with ng-repeat, but I want blank results to show on my child ng-repeat. Is there any way to do that? I have an element structure I want to be shown from the child ng-repeat.

The code looks like this :

```
<ng-repeat="row in parentArray"> <--- the parent array
{{row.name}}
{{row.date}}
{{row.place}}

    <ng-repeat="option in row"> <--- the child array
    Result : {{option.name}} <-- I still want result to show up

</ng-repeat>
</ng-repeat>
```

Comment: This is unclear. You want to display blank results where an option exists but the name is not set, or is it when an option doesn't exist? The first should be the current result, and the second is just... confusing? Please give us some context.

Comment: Basically on the parent array there sometimes is a property, in which the value is a child array of options. Currently my second ng-repeat will not show data

Answer (score 2):

If i understand you correctly, you wanna show something if there is no option?

`ng-repeat` only works with data. When there is no data, nothing is displayed. For this purpose you can use `ng-if` or `ng-show` / `ng-hide`

Also it is very unclear for me at the moment, where the options are stored in the row

HTML

```
<ng-repeat="row in parentArray"> <--- the parent array
{{row.name}}
{{row.date}}
{{row.place}}


    <div ng-if="row.options.length > 0">
        <ng-repeat="option in row.options"> <--- the child array
        Result : {{option.name}} <-- I still want result to show up
    </div>
    <div ng-if="row.options.length === 0">
       <label>No Data</label>
    </div>

</ng-repeat>
```